# Change the behavior of any running process

Tags: decompiler

Would it be possible to develop a program that decompiles the instructions of a running process, for example into a C-like language, and allows them to be modified and then injected into the process itself, changing its behavior?

Comment: Yes, but what is the point since you can modify assembler instructions directly, with much much less effort?

Comment: Wouldn't C or C++ be more comfortable and readable than Assembly?

Comment: Don't think so. Something as perfect C or C++ decompiler doesn't exist. They are often more confusing than assembly, and sometimes just wrong.

Comment: Would such a decompiler be technically impossible or just very difficult to develop?

Comment: @Axeryon The main problem of decompilers is that the generated assembler code can be very different depending on which compiler (and what compile options) was used to generate it. Writing a decompiler for one specific compiler with one specific set of options is difficult. However you have hundred of compilers that can generate e.g. x86 binary code with thousands of options that can be applied. You can see that writing a general decompiler that is generating compilable and correct code is more than a life-time job.

Comment: Let's consider a specific operating system and a specific CPU. Would each compiler generate code belonging to the instruction set supported by that CPU?
If so, wouldn't it be enough to decompile it into semantically equivalent code valid for at least one specific compiler?

Comment: @Axeryon yes, and decompilers exist, but it would be very difficult to modify the decompilation to fit back into the program

Comment: So this is the problem, it would be difficult to inject the new modified code into the process